# How to hide android navigation-bar(back/home/menu) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-navigation-bar

I want to build an app without native navigation bar, like back/home/recent. I would not use fullscreen mode, for that I need to display the status bar. In Flutter, I use the code SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]); it works for the beginning, bottom bar comes back when tap anywhere on screen.

My Flutter version:

Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework • revision 7a4c33425d (3 weeks ago) • 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700

Engine • revision 52c7a1e849

Tools • Dart 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)